# Create nested objects from CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file which needs to be processed into objects.

I can open the CSV file and get all the contents that I want, no problem there. I need to match the contents of the CSV file by headers into objects. For example:

```
Name | Address.Street | Address.Country | Notes.Example.Value

Object->Name
Object->Address
Object->Notes
etc.
```

How would I handle this dynamically, not knowing what the headers are going to be beforehand?

Essentially I want to turn a string, like "Prop.Prop.Prop.etc" into a nested object.

```
$headers = array(); // First row of CSV.
$row = array(); // Current row of CSV.
$record = new StdClass();
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  $properties = explode('.', $headers[$key]);
  if (count($properties > 1)) {
    // ???
  }
  else {
    $record->{$properties[0]} = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done through a recursion. If the property you're parsing has only one level of depth, then you set the object key as a value. (which you're already doing)

If it has two or more levels, you shift the first element of the property array and recurse on the remaining levels.

Elaborating in your example:

```
<?php 

$headers=[
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Address.Street',
        'Address.Country',
        'Notes.Example.Value'
    ];

$row=[
        'john',
        'john@gmail.com',
        'beale street',
        'US',
        '180'
    ];


function setObject(&$object, $properties, $value) {

    $name=array_shift($properties);

    if(count($properties)===0) {
        return $object->{$name} = $value;
    } else {
        // if this property isn't set, we declare it as a new object
        if(!isset($object->{$name}) || !is_object($object->{$name})) $object->{$name} = new StdClass();
        return setObject($object->{$name}, $properties,$value);
    }
}


$record = new StdClass();

foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
    $properties = explode('.', $headers[$key]);
    setObject($record, $properties, $value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($record);
echo '</pre>';
```

This is probably not the most elegant solution. With a bit of work you could avoid passing the object by reference back and forth.